# Why is OnCollisionExit not called?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When i changing character player ( Disable old and Enable new in same transform ) does not catch OnCollisionExit but catches new OnCollisionEnter

When i just go away all work good

Player has rigidbody, enemy has kinematic rigidbody,but it dont work whitch non kinematic rigitbody too

Where did I go wrong?

P.S Sorry for my english

```
       [SerializeField] private Enemy attacker;

        public event Action OnAttack;

        private Player _player;

        private int _layerPlayer = 6;
        private bool _play = false;

        private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
        {
            Debug.Log("contact");
            if (collision.gameObject.layer == _layerPlayer)
            {
                _player = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Player>();
                if (_player != null)
                {
                    Debug.Log(_player.name);
                    StartCoroutine(InvokePerSec(_player));
                }
                
            }
        }
        private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
        {
            Debug.Log("leave");
            if (collision.gameObject.layer == _layerPlayer)
            {
                _play = false;
            }
        }
        IEnumerator InvokePerSec(Player _player)
        {
            _play = true;

            while (_play)
            {
                float health = _player.Health;

                _player.GetComponent<HealthSystem>()?.TakeDamage(ref health, attacker._attackDamage);

                _player.Health = health;

                OnAttack?.Invoke();

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            }
        }
```

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhkON.png)

git project: https://github.com/velpover/3D_Ghosts.git

Comment: I believe we need way more information to help you. Anyways I assume that the new character propbably is not registered to the event. Please add further information.

Comment: I have added all the code in the script.
Each character has its own hp and I need only the selected character to react, the rest are in an inactive state ,somethink like this:                              
         (_redPlayer.SetActive(false);
        _yellowPlayer.SetActive(false);
        _blackPlayer.SetActive(true);)

Comment: When you use "SetActive" it could be that `OnCollisionExit` is not called, because the object is not treated as part of the regular update cycle anymore. See [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html): "Deactivating a GameObject disables each component, including attached renderers, colliders, rigidbodies, and scripts. For example, Unity will no longer call the Update() method of a script attached to a deactivated GameObject."